# SQL Delete row from table syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

removebutton_Click

```
protected void removebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string RemoveSQL;

    OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
    mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
                           + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/database.accdb");
    mDB.Open(); OleDbCommand cmd;

    Button removebutton = (Button)sender;
    Label carttransactionlabel = (Label)removebutton.Parent.FindControl("carttransactionlabel");

    int intTransNo = int.Parse(carttransactionlabel.Text);

    RemoveSQL = "DELETE FROM orderItems"
                + "WHERE iTransaction_No = @TransNo";

    cmd = new OleDbCommand(RemoveSQL, mDB);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TransNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = intTransNo;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    mDB.Close();
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is that when the user clicks on the `removebutton` button, the SQL command `RemoveSQL` will remove the entire row of transaction from the `orderItems` table in MS Access based on the transaction number (`carttransactionlabel`).

Table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLETp.png)

However, when I try to click on the removebutton button, this error appears 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQGlD.png)

Apparently there's a syntax error in the SQL statement which I can't seem to spot. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Missing a space between orderItems and WHERE

Answer (score 2):

Print out your SQL before running it!  At least some problems will be obvious.

You have this code:

```
RemoveSQL = "DELETE FROM orderItems" + "WHERE iTransaction_No = @TransNo";
```

If you print this out, it will look like:

```
RemoveSQL = "DELETE FROM orderItemsWHERE iTransaction_No = @TransNo";
```

The error and fix should be obvious.

Note:  You may have other issues in your code.